# vb.net - how to make the following "with" statements simple in module?

Tags: vb.net, with-statement

I have 1 module and 7 forms

As you can see Im duplicating all the codes except form1, form2, form3, are there ways to make this simple for with statement?

```
Module ModuleMessageCenter
  Public Sub MessageCenterDatagrid()
    Try            
        Call ConnectDatabase()
        Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT IdMessage, Subject, Description, Priority, DateReceived, Deadline, OFR, Attachment FROM message ORDER BY IdMessage DESC", sqlcon)
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        adapter.Fill(table)

        '>>>> how to make the following "with" statements simple? <<<<

        With form1 
            .MessageDataGridView.DataSource = table
        End With
        With form2
            .MessageDataGridView.DataSource = table
        End With
        With form3
            .MessageDataGridView.DataSource = table
        End With
    Catch 'er As Exception
        'MsgBox(er.Message)
    End Try
  End Sub
```

> > > > As you can see Im duplicating all the codes except form1, form2, form3, are there ways to make this simple for with statement? <<<<

```
    Public Sub GridValues()

         With form1

            .lblIdMessage.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("IdMessage", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
            .SubjectTextBox.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("Subject", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString 'in the place of column name u can also place the column index .
            .DescriptionTextBox.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("Description", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
            .ComboPriotity.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("Priority", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
            .txtDateReceived.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("DateReceived", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
            .txtDeadLine.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("Deadline", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
            .ComboOFR.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("OFR", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
            .txtAttach.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("Attachment", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString

      End With

      With form2

            .lblIdMessage.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("IdMessage", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
            .SubjectTextBox.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("Subject", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString 'in the place of column name u can also place the column index .
            .DescriptionTextBox.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("Description", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
            .ComboPriotity.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("Priority", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
            .txtDateReceived.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("DateReceived", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
            .txtDeadLine.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("Deadline", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
            .ComboOFR.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("OFR", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
            .txtAttach.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("Attachment", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString

   End With

   With form3

            .lblIdMessage.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("IdMessage", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
            .SubjectTextBox.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("Subject", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString 'in the place of column name u can also place the column index .
            .DescriptionTextBox.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("Description", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
            .ComboPriotity.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("Priority", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
            .txtDateReceived.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("DateReceived", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
            .txtDeadLine.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("Deadline", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
            .ComboOFR.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("OFR", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
            .txtAttach.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("Attachment", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString

 End With

 End Sub
```

As you can see Im duplicating all the codes except form1, form2, form3 in Module, are there ways to make this simple for with statement?

```
  Public Sub MessageCenterDownloadFile()

    With form1

        Try
            Dim SaveFileToFolder As New SaveFileDialog
            SaveFileToFolder.FileName = .SubjectTextBox.Text
            If SaveFileToFolder.ShowDialog().Equals(DialogResult.OK) Then
                Dim Cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT AttachmentFile FROM message WHERE IdMessage =" & .lblIdMessage.Text, sqlcon)
                Dim fileBytes() As Byte = DirectCast(Cmd.ExecuteScalar, Byte())
                'IO.File.WriteAllBytes(.SubjectTextBox.Text + .txtAttach.Text, fileBytes) 'IO.File.WriteAllBytes("path", fileBytes)
                My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(SaveFileToFolder.FileName + .txtAttach.Text, fileBytes, True)
                MessageBox.Show("Download Successful!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                'Call MessageCenterDatagrid() 'REFRESH DATA
            End If
        Catch
        End Try

   End With

   With form2

        Try
            Dim SaveFileToFolder As New SaveFileDialog
            SaveFileToFolder.FileName = .SubjectTextBox.Text
            If SaveFileToFolder.ShowDialog().Equals(DialogResult.OK) Then
                Dim Cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT AttachmentFile FROM message WHERE IdMessage =" & .lblIdMessage.Text, sqlcon)
                Dim fileBytes() As Byte = DirectCast(Cmd.ExecuteScalar, Byte())
                'IO.File.WriteAllBytes(.SubjectTextBox.Text + .txtAttach.Text, fileBytes) 'IO.File.WriteAllBytes("path", fileBytes)
                My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(SaveFileToFolder.FileName + .txtAttach.Text, fileBytes, True)
                MessageBox.Show("Download Successful!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                'Call MessageCenterDatagrid() 'REFRESH DATA
            End If
        Catch
    End Try

  End With

  With form3
        Try
            Dim SaveFileToFolder As New SaveFileDialog
            SaveFileToFolder.FileName = .SubjectTextBox.Text
            If SaveFileToFolder.ShowDialog().Equals(DialogResult.OK) Then
                Dim Cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT AttachmentFile FROM message WHERE IdMessage =" & .lblIdMessage.Text, sqlcon)
                Dim fileBytes() As Byte = DirectCast(Cmd.ExecuteScalar, Byte())
                'IO.File.WriteAllBytes(.SubjectTextBox.Text + .txtAttach.Text, fileBytes) 'IO.File.WriteAllBytes("path", fileBytes)
                My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(SaveFileToFolder.FileName + .txtAttach.Text, fileBytes, True)
                MessageBox.Show("Download Successful!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                'Call MessageCenterDatagrid() 'REFRESH DATA
            End If
        Catch
        End Try

    End With
```

End Sub

```
End module
```

Comment: Is there a need to use it at all if you are just settings one property?

Comment: how to do it Sir?

Comment: The point of a `With` block is to make multiple accesses of the same object simple. In your case, you're not accessing the same object so this is not a situation to use a `With` block. The fact that you might want to doesn't make it logical or reasonable.

Comment: I edited my post, actually I have multiple ,same code. The only code that chage is form1, form2, form3

Comment: write a common function for it - see my answer

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing any of this work outside the forms. If there's something to be done with the controls on a form it should be the form itself doing it. If you have common UI and code in several forms then, ideally, you should be putting all that into one form and then using that as a base class for all the others. If you have three forms that all inherit a single base class that contains all the common UIO and code, all you then have to do is call one method on each form and everything else happens inside the forms and in the common code.

Comment: Ok thank you Sir, I will just then do what you have said and transfer it.

Answer (score 1):

`With` is usually used when you are setting several properties of the object. Just access the properties directly:

```
form1.MessageDataGridView.DataSource = table
form2.MessageDataGridView.DataSource = table
form3.MessageDataGridView.DataSource = table
```

Comment: I have several properties and a long code inside with statement.

Comment: inside module

 Public Sub MessageCenterAdd()
        With form1
            .SubjectTextBox.Clear()
            .DescriptionTextBox.Clear()
            .ComboPriotity.ResetText()
            .txtDateReceived.Clear()
            .ComboOFR.ResetText()
            .txtAttach.Clear()

            .SubjectTextBox.Select()
            .DTPickerDateReceived.ResetText()
            .DTPickerDeadLine.ResetText()
            .txtDeadLine.Clear()
        End With

    End Sub

I have 7 forms,

Answer (score 0):

> create a function that accepts your form as parameter and write
>   duplicating code inside it

```
Public Sub GridValues()
    GridValuesFor(form1)
    GridValuesFor(form2)
    GridValuesFor(form3)
End Sub

Public Sub GridValuesFor(ByVal thisForm As Form)
    With thisForm
        .lblIdMessage.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("IdMessage", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
        .SubjectTextBox.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("Subject", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString 'in the place of column name u can also place the column index .
        .DescriptionTextBox.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("Description", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
        .ComboPriotity.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("Priority", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
        .txtDateReceived.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("DateReceived", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
        .txtDeadLine.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("Deadline", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
        .ComboOFR.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("OFR", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
        .txtAttach.Text = .MessageDataGridView.Item("Attachment", .MessageDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
    End With
End Sub
```

same for - MessageCenterDownloadFile()

Comment: Hello Sir, there is an error saying .lblIdMessage.Text is not a member of system.windows.forms.form.

Comment: In order for this code to work, you'd have to enable late-binding, which means setting `Option Strict Off`. You could do that just for one file but I wouldn't recommend it for this. A better option would be to put all this common functionality into a base form class and then inherit that in your other three forms. You can then simply call a method on one of those forms and they will do the work themselves, which is how it should be when making UI changes.

Comment: Monkey D Luffy create interface in from and inherit all your forms from this base class, also define type of function parameter to this class